# Como faço para acessar uma posição em um vetor de caracteres?

Tags: r

O seguinte código me retorna um vetor de 12 letras:

```
res <- "ACDEDEAEDCED"
res <- strsplit(res,"", FALSE)
View(res[4])
```

> Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : índice fora de limites

Mais quando tento acessar uma posição e especifica dá erro.
Já tentei de inúmeras formas. Entre elas: `res[1,4]` e `res[,4]`...

Answer (score 3):

A função `strsplit` retorna uma lista, assim o vetor `res` é uma lista, veja:

```
res <- "ACDEDEAEDCED"
res <- strsplit(res,"", FALSE)
res
[[1]]
 [1] "A" "C" "D" "E" "D" "E" "A" "E" "D" "C" "E" "D"
```

Se você quiser o elemento 4 do primeiro elemento da lista, você pode pegar da seguinte forma:

```
res[[1]][4]
[1] "E"
```

Comment: Pode-se usar `unlist(strsplit(res,"", FALSE))` ou `strsplit(res,"", FALSE)[[1]]` para que o resultado final seja um vetor, sendo que o primeiro agrupa todos resultados do `strsplit` e o segundo mantém apenas o primeiro.